# onchange in select tag does not call function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-scope, onchange

I am trying to create a drop-down menu using the `<select>` tag in html as follows,

```
<select id="Parameter1" onchange="function1()">
  <option value = "0105" name = "Frequency">Frequency</option>
  <option value = "0106" name = "Motor Current">Motor Current</option>
</select>
```

The angularJS function I am trying to call is follows,

```
$scope.function1 = function(){
  var paramId = document.getElementById("Parameter1").value; 
}
```

The result leads to an error stating: `Uncaught ReferenceError: function1 is not defined`

Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using AngularJS, you need to use `ng-*` directives:

```
<select id="Parameter1" ng-change="function1()">
  <option value = "0105" name = "Frequency">Frequency</option>
  <option value = "0106" name = "Motor Current">Motor Current</option>
</select>
```

The `ng-change` attribute is an AngularJS Directive, and ties with your `$scope` and is dynamic, while `onchange` is just the native JavaScript event.

This holds true for most of them:

- `ng-src`
- `ng-href`
- `ng-click`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-change` directive instead of `onchange` as `function1` is under the `scope` of the controller.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.value = '0105';
  $scope.function1 = function() {
    alert($scope.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <select id="Parameter1" ng-change="function1()" ng-model='value'>
    <option value="0105" name="Frequency">Frequency</option>
    <option value="0106" name="Motor Current">Motor Current</option>
  </select>
  {{value}}
</div>
```

To use `onchange`, your handler function must be under the global `scope`

**Edit:** Also consider the implementation of the `function1`, While dealing with angular, use `scope` variables.

Comment: Actually, I have multiple ng-views and by adding ng-change all the views intersect together with this view. 
That is okay but still `ng-change` also does not work when I select any value in the dropdown.
Yes it is in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `ng-change` directive. The `onchange` callback is used in pure DOM.

Angular says: "Evaluate the given expression when the user changes the input. The expression is evaluated immediately, unlike the JavaScript onchange event which only triggers at the end of a change (usually, when the user leaves the form element or presses the return key)"

Take a look: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange